# String Split based on Ç

Tags: java, split

I want to split a string based on Ç (Latin Capital letter C with cedilla)
so far i have tried string.split, Splitter.on(pattern).split(line)

Ç has unicode 00C7

Comment: Post the exact string you want to split, the code you tried, and its result, it will get you better responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your java source file is in UTF-8 as it should be, this perfectly works :

```
String[] token = s.split("Ç");
```

If not, use

```
String[] token = s.split("\u00C7"); // Ç
```

but this is much less readable

Comment: well i have tried both of these, i have to do it on unix and it is not working. my input looks like somenumber?somenumber and as per the information i have ? is Ç which unix can't read

Comment: I tested this on linux, no problem... Are you sure of the code of the character you get and of the reading process ? How are you getting your string ?

Comment: @zuxqoj either your character encoding is not correct, or your file doesn't contain the character you think it is.  There is nothing special but the character you want to split on and I see no reason to suspect its the cause of your problem.

Comment: ok, so the problem was in the way i was reading file, i was reading file by char instead of by byte

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
String s = "I want to split a string based on Ç (Latin Capital letter C with cedilla) so far i have tried string.split, Splitter.on(pattern).split(line)\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Ç has unicode 00C7";
for(String part: s.split("Ç"))
    System.out.println("["+part+"]");
```

prints

```
[I want to split a string based on ]
[ (Latin Capital letter C with cedilla) so far i have tried string.split, Splitter.on(pattern).split(line)

]
[ has unicode 00C7]
```